# Store/Retrieve Json data to/from Mysql 5.7 database using hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, mysql-5.7

I am going to start a project where I need to generate dynamic google forms. The requirement for this project is I need to use mysql 5.7 so that I could use json datatype to store/retrieve json data. I am fine with this. I know, it is possible using HQL. But what I couldn't figure out is how do I implement it with Hibernate using object relational mapping ?

Any Ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would guess it is possible, however I don't think there is a simple way, certainly it's a lot of work... Do you know `torodb`? They are doing sort of the same thing, however I guess they don't use `HQL` and underneath they have `postgresql`... Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

Recently I have solved similar task. I guess it's too late, but maybe someone finds this useful.

**Short answer**: you should create class (like "*com.test.MyJsonType*") that must implement *org.hibernate.usertype.UserType* interface where the *nullSafeGet* method should deserialize JSON to java object (using Jackson), the *nullSafeSet* serialize POJO to JSON and some other auxiliary methods.

Then you should extend MySQLDialect and register new column type "json".

Finally you can annotate entity fields by @Type(type = "*com.test.MyJsonType*") which should be mapped to MySQL json columns.

You may also read about @TypeDef [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794) if you don't want write type with package name.

For example:

```
public class MyJsonType implements UserType {

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };
}

@Override
public Class<Characteristics> returnedClass() {
    return Characteristics.class;
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor session, final Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    final String cellContent = rs.getString(names[0]);
    if (cellContent == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper.readValue(cellContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), returnedClass());
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert String to Invoice: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement ps, final Object value, final int idx, final SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value == null) {
        ps.setNull(idx, Types.VARCHAR);
        return;
    }
    try {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        mapper.writeValue(w, value);
        w.flush();
        ps.setObject(idx, w.toString(), Types.VARCHAR);
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert Invoice to String: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}

@Override
public Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(value);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        bos.close();

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
        return new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
        throw new HibernateException(ex);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Serializable disassemble(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return (Serializable) this.deepCopy(value);
}

@Override
public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return this.deepCopy(cached);
}

@Override
public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return this.deepCopy(original);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
    return Objects.equals(x, y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    return Objects.hashCode(x);
}

}
```

POJO class:

```
public class Characteristics implements Serializable {

private String field;

public String getField() {
    return field;
}

public void setField(String field) {
    this.field= field;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    final Characteristics other = (Characteristics) obj;
    return Objects.equals(this.field, other.field);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(this.field);

}
}
```

Register new column type:

```
public class JsonMySQLDialect extends MySQLDialect {

public JsonMySQLDialect() {
    this.registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "json");
}

}
```

Using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table")
public class TableClass {
...
@Column
@Type(type = "com.test.MyJsonType")
protected Characteristics characteristics;
...
}
```

Comment: Does it create a the column of type "json" or varchar?

Comment: It creates "json" column type.

Comment: Java automatically calls super(). But if you want you may explicitly call it.

Comment: Hi, Could you give me an example involving an array such as characteristics being an array.

Comment: @user5500750 I think you can just do the following inside `TableClass`:
`protected Characteristics[] characteristics;`

I haven't tested it though so don't quote me on that.