# Map Json string in Mysql's json type column vai hibernate

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate

I am looking to create json data type column in MySQL via hibernate during startup. I don't want any kind of transformation while saving or fetching data. I just want to store json string ( rather than an object) into json column.
How could I achieve via hibernate.
Any idea or hint, please ?

Comment: MySQL will reconstruct your JSON value (the value retrieved may differ from the value saved - in components ordering) if you'll use JSON datatype column. Is it safe for you? If not then use VARCHAR/TEXT datatype instead.

Comment: @Akina At max I assume, MySQL would reorder the keys of JSON and nothing much. I am okay with it. The problem lies in that Hibernate does not identify "JSON" type.

Comment: *At max I assume, MySQL would reorder the keys of JSON and nothing much.* That's true. For some OPs the physical order makes sense somewhy...

Comment: @Akina Do you know how could I introduce JSON type in hibernate ?

Comment: See, for example, [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/#:~:text=MySQL%20).

Comment: @Akina He is suggesting to use his library which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52748015/10138734 (see both upvoted comment and accepted answer), https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146161/10138734 and so on...

Comment: @Akin Thanks but I am unable to find how to specify   columnDefinition = "json" in xml hibernate xml file. We are using hibernate xml file instead of class annotation.

Comment: @Akina I used "sql-type=json" in hibernate config xml. It created column with json data type. Testing further to see behavior during crud operation.

Comment: Please create self-answer with your solution (and some explainations) - maybe it will help to somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following xml property ("sql-type") to create json data type:
E.g:

```
        <property name="template">
            <column name="template" sql-type="json"/>
        </property>
```

This was enough for me as I am not looking for transformation between json and object. For transformation, one can create converter.

Thanks to @Akina for helping me with useful links and suggestion.